# Solving resource interdependencies in AWS Cloudformation, using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I've a situation here, where two AWS resources are interdependent. How could we resolve or what's the best solution in the below mentioned situation?

There are two constructs, one for creating SNS topic and other for Lambda function. The SNS requires lambda function ARN for adding a subscription, whereas lambda function requires SNS topic ARN for adding it to an environment variable. How can this dependency be resolved with CDK (preferably in .NET)?

Code:

```
public class AllStacks : Stack
{
   public AllStacks(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
   {
      var lambdaFn = new LambdaFnConstruct(this, "LambdaFunction");
      new SNSConstruct(this, "SnsTopic", lambdaFn.lambdaARN);      
   }
}
```

Lambda Construct:

```
internal LambdaFnConstruct(Construct scope, string id, Role role) : base(scope, id)
{
    var lambdaFn = new Function(this, "LambdaCDK", new FunctionProps()
    {
        //Some code here...
        Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
           {"SNS_ARN", /* Need to provide SNS ARN here */ },
        },
    });
}
```

SNS Construct:

```
public SNSConstruct(Construct scope, string id, string lambdaARN) : base(scope, id)
{
    Topic topic = new Topic(this, "Messaging", new TopicProps()
    {
        TopicName = "Messaging"
    });
    Subscription subscription = new Subscription(this, "Topic subscription", new SubscriptionProps()
    {
        Topic = topic,
        Protocol = SubscriptionProtocol.LAMBDA,
        Endpoint = lambdaARN, //<----Lambda ARN goes here
    });
}
```

Lambda function streaming message to AWS Connect:

```
public async Task EnableMessageStreamingAsync(string channel, string contactID)
{
   try
   {
     StartContactStreamingRequest startContactStreamingRequest = new StartContactStreamingRequest()
      {
        ContactId = contactID,
        InstanceId = instanceID,
        ChatStreamingConfiguration = new ChatStreamingConfiguration()
        {
          StreamingEndpointArn = streamEndpointARN //<--- Here goes the SNS ARN
        }
      };

  await connectClient.StartContactStreamingAsync(startContactStreamingRequest);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Error messgae: {ex.Message}");
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
  }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, it seems strange that the Lambda needs to be provided with the ARN of the SNS topic: it should be able to get that information from the invocation event.

Comment: It should also be a non-issue: the CDK app will generate three CloudFormation resources: a Lambda, an SNS Topic, and an SNS Subscription. CloudFormation will handle the ordering of actual resource creation. However, you probably won't be able to use your own SNS construct, instead creating the two resources separately.

Comment: The lambda needs SNS ARN for the fact that it’s job is to stream messages to the topic, hence the need.

Comment: I agree with @kdgregory, I don't understand why your lambda would be a subscriber to the sns topic and would require to know the sns topic arn. Can you share some of the lambda code to illustrate how you're using the sns topic arn inside the lambda handler?

Comment: @MatthewBonig, I've added coded under 'Lambda function streaming message to AWS Connect' heading, further, here is a reference document explaining the scenario: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/adding-digital-messaging-channels-to-your-amazon-connect-contact-center/

Comment: I believe the point was that when you create a subscription and it invokes your lambda, the event payload will contain the SNS topic ARN - you don't need to provide it separately via the environment variables.

Comment: @gshpychka, it is not the SNS subscription that invokes the Lambda, but an APIGateway. The payload is then sent by Lambda to AWS Connect and to SNS topic, hence the requirement of SNS ARN in Lambda. You can refer to the this document as what I'm trying to do: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/adding-digital-messaging-channels-to-your-amazon-connect-contact-center/

Comment: In the code you provided, the SNS subscription invokes the lambda.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution, I can add environment variable post the creation of Lambda using this method:

```
public virtual Function AddEnvironment (string key, string value, IEnvironmentOptions? options = null)
```

So once SNS topic is created (which is Lambda dependent), I can add a variable later.

Comment: This will not work. You cannot have a circular dependency.

Comment: It does work, perfectly.

Comment: If it works, then the SNS topic doesn't depend on the lambda. The fact remains that this is not the way to do this.

Comment: Sure, agreed. It doesn't depend, but requires SNS ARN.

Comment: The SNS topic requires SNS ARN?

Comment: Sorry, Lambda ARN

Comment: That cannot be true, that would make it depend on the lambda. Can you post a minimal code to reproduce this? I must be missing something.

Comment: Looks like even I'm missing something. However, I got this working, issue is now resolved.

Comment: I get that, I'm just trying to understand what's going on here to make this answer helpful for others. Can you post your CDK code where you're calling `addEnvironment`?